# All I need to do is to post 3 values! Android to PHP server script

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

Code on the android device is:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {


    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
    }
```

Code on the PHP server is:

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);

    if($user){
            echo json_encode($response). "User Stored Successfully";
        } 
        else{
            echo json_encode($response). "Error Occured in Registration";
        }
```

where storeUser is:

```
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email','$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");

    }
```

The process works, sends a message back to the android device, but the details are not
inserted into the MySQL database?

All I want is to post the details from an android device and insert them into a MySQL database on my server.

Anyone know why this is being caused, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: tutorial on how to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong with my code from above.

The url passed to the httppost in the java/android code did not work as a simple address to the api I am using, I tried www.domain.com/index.php? with the '?'. Adding this made the code work.

I just went back to basics, looking at what makes a post

here is a reference to the POST article in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP), it helped me to figure out what made up a http post

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['password'];
```

That's obviously wrong. Change the variables to `$email` and `$password`.

Also, stop using mysql_query as it's getting [deprecated](http://php.net/mysql_query). Make use of either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.